Product of a distribution and a function nonzero a.e. equals the zero function
I'm working on a problem where I ran into the following question.
Let $1<p \leq 2$ and let $f\in A^p(\mathbb{T})$ be nonzero a.e. Assume that $g\in (A^p(\mathbb{T}))^* = A^{p'}(\mathbb{T})$ is such that $\langle g, fe^{2\pi inx}\rangle = 0$ (Here $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is intepreted from distribution point of view) for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Does this imply $g=0?$.
By the uniqueness of Fourier coefficients, we can see that $gf$ is the zero function.
So, the answer is yes if $g$ is a function, which means the answer is true if $p=2$.
However, $g$ needs not to be a function if $p<2$ and that's where I got stuck. Any feedback or reference would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: Another point of view is to see if $(f\cdot A^p(\mathbb{T}))\cap A^p(\mathbb{T})$ is a dense subset of $A^p(\mathbb{T})$ when $f\neq 0$ a.e. This is true for $p=2$ and $p=1$ (by Wiener's lemma).

... presumably your "$A^p$" is what many people would call "$L^p$"? And $1/p+1/p'=1$? If you can confirm, then I think I have a helpful answer for you.

Here $A^p(T)$ denotes the set of distributions on torus with p-summable Fourier coefficients (the nth Fourier coefficient of g is defined by <g, e_n>, where $e_n=e^{2\pi i nx}$). So, $A^p(T)$ is not $L^p$ except $p=2$. And you are right, 1/p+1/p'=1. Any idea would be appreciated.

After some reflection, I think there's no trivial answer... pointwise-vanishing-or-not is non-trivial to detect from Fourier coefficients.

I think you are right. Still no idea how to proceed. Thanks anyway.
